# WPF: Binding in TabItem header

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

I want to display in tab item header "*" (star), when the content of TabItem is modified (bound data).
I have following style of TabItem:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="_border" 
                                Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                Padding="0 0 5 0" 
                                Background="Transparent" 
                                BorderBrush="Black" 
                                BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" 
                                CornerRadius="1">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 2 0 2">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Name="_header">
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                      ContentSource="Header" 
                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True">
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <Button Name="_close"
                                        Visibility="Hidden"
                                        Style="{StaticResource _closeButtonStyle}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}"
                                        Click="CloseTab_Click"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        Margin="10 0 0 0"
                                        Width="16"
                                        Height="16">
                                    <Image Source="Images/delete_icon16_white.png"
                                           Width="10"
                                           Height="10"
                                           Cursor="Hand"/>
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="_header" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="_close" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="_border" Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter TargetName="_header" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="_close" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="_border" Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuHighlightColorKey}}"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

How to add to this style mentioned "*", when property *IsModified* of bound data is set to true?

Thank you for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a TextBlock on the header with Text="*".

Then bind its visibility with the IsModified property and a booleanToVisibility Converter

EDIT:
Binding Visibility

```
Visibility="{Binding IsModified, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

And in your Resources file

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

EDIT2: Don't know if you need this info but just for the case. An approach to the HeaderTemplate

```
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
          <TextBlock Text="*" Visibility="{Binding IsModified, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion... care to show the user how to do that?

Comment: Well it was a clue so the OP could find the answer, the binding of the visibility i think should be:

Visibility="{Binding IsModified, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"

Comment: Think of the bigger picture...it's not just this user that will be looking for an answer to this problem. Also, the more helpful your answer is, the more reputation you will receive from the StackOverflow community.

Comment: You are right. Next time I'll write full answer at the beginning. I'm quite new at wpf and I didn't want to answer in a wrong way. Hope my editions  are correct.

Comment: javi I have already tried this but it wasnt working. I realised where is the problem, so now I am refactoring my code... Anyway, your suggestion is correct.